# Angular 2 dynamic nested router outlets

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a scenario in which I have to copy the way quick edit works on wordpress.

Based on what I understand you can do on router-outlet like this

```
<div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <router-outlet name="quick"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

and you can use it by entering localhost:4200/users(quick:quick-edit).

Now my scenario is I want to load all the users on a grid. Under the grid
There will be 3 small buttons Edit | Quick Edit | Trash

[image]

When I clicked Edit it will call the edit on a new page. So using router-outlet
 /router-outlet only works fine however if I click Quick Edit
it will still show the users in grid and change the selected row into a quick edit form. Based on that scenario it should look like this

```
<router-outlet>
     <table>
         <tr>

         </tr>
         <router-outlet name="quick"></router-outlet>
     </table> <!-- It will be loaded once quick edit is pressed -->
</router-outlet>
```

but it seems it is not possible? Any idea or work around to make it working?

Comment: this can be done in multiple ways but how separately your had your components? `quick-edit` and `edit` are same components?

Comment: no, they are different

Comment: Edit will load the FormUserComponent, while Quick Edit will load FormQuickUserComponent including the user grid, it will then hide the row where I click Quick Edit and show the quick edit form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the edit and quick edit both are same you need not use a separate router inside the table component. But you can handle it as

The main router outlet

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The table component should be  as

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users"></tr>
    <quick-edit-component *ngIf="user.quickEdit" [user]="user"> </quick-edit-component>
</table>
```

The complete edit can be routed using the url.

URL : ->

```
localhost:2000/users              ------------users table view

localhost:2000/users/edit/:id     ------------users full edit view

the quick edit will have no route path
```

Comment: So it is fine to load the quick edit form immediately after you load the grid and then hide it. Anyway your answer is the best solution I think. I wonder why nested router outlet is not possible.